# Django request URL gets appended

Tags: python, django, redirect

i visit admin interface and try to add support user in django.its a form with user name and email. the form data is posted successfully. after successful post request i have to redirect to **127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/**. however at **127.0.0.1:8000/add_support_user** if user exists already,url is changed like this **127.0.0.1:8000/add_support_user/add_support_user** and again i make request if user already exists its like this **127.0.0.1:8000/add_support_user/add_support_user/add_support_user**(gets appended every time) [support_User_form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o15TB.png) and when new user is created url is changed like this **127.0.0.1:8000/add_support_user/add_support_user** so it shows 500 error page that **'127.0.0.1:8000/add_support_user/add_support_user'** doesnt exists [error_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8HOp.png). what mistake am i making here?

**URLS.PY**

```
 url(r"^add_support_user/", AddSupportUserView.as_view(), name = 'support_user'),
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
class AddSupportUserView(CsrfExemptMixin, View):
def get(self, request):
    form_class = AddSupportUserForm

    return render(request, 'add_support_user.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })

def post(self, request):
    form_class = AddSupportUserForm

    username = request.POST.get('username')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    try:
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return render(request, 'add_support_user.html', {'errors': 'User already exits', 'form': form_class})
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user_obj = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, is_staff=True,
                                            is_superuser=False)
        user_obj.set_password(email)
        user_obj.save()
    group_obj = Group.objects.get(name='support_group')
    user_obj.groups.add(group_obj)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/auth/user/')
```

**CHANGE_LIST.HTML**

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %} {% block object-tools-items %} {{ 
block.super }}
<li>
<a href="{% url 'support_user' %}" class="grp-state-focus addlink">Add   
Support User</a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

**ADD_SUPPORT_USER.HTML**

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}{% block content %}
<h1>Add Support User</h1>
<form role="form" action="add_support_user/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<label style="color:red;">*{{errors}}</label>
<table>
    {% for field in form %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="{{ field.label }}" style="display:inline- 
block;vertical-align:middle">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ field }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input style="float:left;" type="submit" value="Save" class="default"  
name="_save">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `group_obj = Group.objects.get(name='support_group')` check this group exists in DB please

Comment: @Nikitka why? what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's about 500 error

Comment: @Nikitka yes suppport_group exists.

Comment: @Nikitka url redirection is not performed after POST . why?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you still have 500 error on user creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your form

```
<form role="form" action="add_support_user/" method="post">
```

to this

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
```

Comment: Or preprend with a `/`